# Chrome javascript debugger pauses on timeouts, can't debug click events

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome, webkit

Almost every webpage has all sorts of timeouts and intervals that are continuously running, so using the pause javascript button in chrome has always just broke on those events and never given me a chance to test anything.

For example, I want to follow what happens when I click something on a page. Instead of digging through the resources, it would be helpful to pause the js, click the thing, and see what code is run. Unfortunately, as soon as I click pause, it breaks on one of the page's interval events.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may find this bookmarklet helpful...and usable in more than just Chrome (though that's where I like to develop too)

[Visual Event](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event)